# PHP Insert into MySQL with button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have a form which has two different actions, one to delete the corresponding MySQL row, the other save it to another database.  The delete function works fine, but the save function does not.  I'm kind of at a loss at what exactly is wrong, any help is appreciated!

**Here's the save/delete code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    include('publishmod.php');
} elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    include('deleterequest.php');
} else {
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

If statements omitted, unimportant to question.  Here is the form:

```
echo "<form name=\"editmod\" id=\"editmod\" method=\"post\">";
   echo "<tr class='modlist'>";
   echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_1\">".$row['title']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_2\"><a href=".$row['mod_url'].">".$row['mod_url']."</a></div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_3\">".$row['developer']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_4\">".$row['type']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_5\">".$v162."$nbsp".$v164."$nbsp".$v172."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_6\">".$row['title'].",$nbsp".$row['developer']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"save\" value=\"Save\" id=\"save\"></td>";
   echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\" id=\"delete\"></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="mod_url" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['mod_url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="developer" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['developer'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['type'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="v162" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['v162'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="v164" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['v164'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="v172" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['v172'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="', htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '" />';
   echo "</form>";
```

Yes, I am aware it has some HTML tag problems, working on that later.

**publishmod.php (the save page) code:**

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$desc = "HowToInstallMods.com installation tutorial for '.$title.'";
$url = ereg("^[A-Za-z_\-]+$", $title) + ".php";
$keywords = "'.$title.','.$_POST['developer'].'";

// Query
```

Simple MySQLi connection and error check omitted.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO search (title, description, url, keywords, type, mod_url, developer, v162, v164, v172) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii", $_POST['title'], $desc, $url, $keywords, $_POST['type'], $_POST['mod_url'], $_POST['developer'], $_POST['v162'], $_POST['v164'], $_POST['v172']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Thanks is advance.

**UPDATES:**

A solution has not yet been found, but here are the changes that have been made so far from people's fixes/suggestions:

- Fixed unmatched $_POST values (thanks to **gfrobenius**)
- Fixed mistake from previous code, which was an if statement, and converted
  to regular variable (thanks to **Arian**)
- Added missing single quotes between values in query (thanks to **damok6**)

Comment: Try using print_r($mysqli->errorInfo()); after the execute to see if the pdo statement produces an error.

Comment: @ssergei Added that before the `$stmt->execute();`, no error was shown, and after the `$stmt->close();` separately, still no error.  I still would not rule out that the statement isn't being run for some reason, but as far as I can see the statement seems like it be being executed.

Comment: Add it after the execute but before the close.

Comment: @ssergei Yep, tried that first, did not print any errors.

Comment: If you are not seeing errors and you are not seeing a record inserted then it seems logical to make sure that code is even being reached.  Put a var_dump($_POST); die(); IMMEDIATELY before your $mysqli->prepare... let us know if you see anything.  Then try what I suggested in my updated answer below.

Comment: I have a feeling it's something with the original file, because I can't even get the `var_dump` to post anything.  The weird thing though, is that the "delete" function works, but not the "save" function.

Comment: Well there you go, I mentioned the var_dump 6 hours ago :) Just keep "dumping" you way back up your other code that you haven't posted til you find the problem. The other 3 issues we all helped you fix would have been problem if your insert WAS being reached so maybe a click up on our answers would be nice since they will end up helping you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you trimmed your form in order to keep your question short but I don't see any of the $_POST vars you are trying to insert.  So it could be erroring because those $_POST vars don't exist and depending on your error settings you may not see the error.

--UPDATED--
Let's rule out one little thing at a time.  Please replace your `$stmt->bind_param` line with this one really quick and just try it and see if anything gets in.

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii", 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Added the rest of the form, should be a little bit clearer now.

Comment: Is some other code turning those divs into fields?  Because I still don't see the $_POST vars you are attempting to insert.  I suggest doing var_dump($_POST); die(); right before your insert and making sure they are all present.  Example: you are trying to insert "developer" but your hidden is named "dev".

Comment: Okay, updated a few things that didn't match, let me know if you see anything else.

Comment: Alright, switched out the line, still no row created, I also have it print any errors, which it did not.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I can quickly see is that the line

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii", $_POST[title], $desc, $url, $keywords, $_POST[type], $_POST[mod_url], $_POST[developer], $_POST[v162], $_POST[v164], $_POST[v172]);
```

is missing all necessary quotation marks for the keys in the $_POST variable, and should read:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssiii", $_POST['title'], $desc, $url, $keywords, $_POST['type'], $_POST['mod_url'], $_POST['developer'], $_POST['v162'], $_POST['v164'], $_POST['v172']);
```

Another issue is that the prepared statement

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...)
```

has 10 '?'s and there are 11 parameters in the bind_param(...) statement.

Comment: Fixed that, thank you, still no solution yet though.

Comment: Cool. Would you mind modifying the original question with that fix to prevent other people offering a similar redundant answer to me. :)

Comment: I'm counting 10 for all sections.

Answer (score 1):

You have what seems to be an extra `) {` at the end of your prepare statement, it should just be a `;`

```
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
                                          ^ what is going on here?
```

Comment: Missed it when I changed it over from an if statement, thanks, but still not luck with the saving.

Comment: you should really post the code in your file, instead of changing it before posting it here... we can't find the bug if you are changing numerous things for posting it on SO

Comment: I have a hard time believing that, because again, you have two parentheses at the end of your prepare statement `));` this would generate a php error easy to see.